# Gtk Grid attach- width wont resize element

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I came across a strange problem. I tried to attach two buttons to the grid: I set width of second to 2, and first to 1, which means that second button will be bigger, than first one. Turned out, that they are the same size. Even setting width value to 100 makes no diffrence.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk','3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self,title="Window")
        self.button1 = Gtk.Button(label="Button1")
        self.button2 = Gtk.Button(label="Button2")
        self.grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(self.grid)
        self.grid.add(self.button1)
        self.grid.attach(self.button2, 1, 0, 2, 1)

win = Window()
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?[That's how app is looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWcn1.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937787/how-can-i-change-the-thickness-of-a-gtkwidget

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev after using `self.grid.set_row_homogeneous(True)` it still doesnt resize button

Comment: Because you need not row, but column homogeneity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the thickness of a gtkwidget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937787/how-can-i-change-the-thickness-of-a-gtkwidget)